# Recovery variable Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make a form with a autocomplete and fields that must be completed according to data entered in the previous field, the data from the database and all that stuff in Wordpress ...

For autocomplete, no problem, it work with Wordpress, I just added a bit of code like:

```
$("#nomPersonne").autocomplete
  ({
     source: 'wp-content/themes/hero-child/listePersone.php'

  });
```

And a page listePersonne like this :

```
<?php

include_once 'connexion.php';

$term = $_GET['term']; 
$requete = $link->prepare("SELECT `wp_terms`.`name` FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` 
JOIN `wp_terms` ON `wp_terms`.`term_id`=`wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id`
WHERE `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy`='nomPersonne' AND `wp_terms`.`name` LIKE :term");

$requete->execute(array('term' => '%' . $term . '%'));

$array = array(); // on créé le tableau

while ($donnee = $requete->fetch()) { // boucle pour obtenir les données
array_push($array, $donnee['name']); // et on ajoute celles-ci à notre tableau
}

echo json_encode($array); // il n'y a plus qu'à convertir en JSON
?>
```

So the list of persons  appears and when one selects one person (if one is found suitable), the following list of organizations will only list the organization(s) of the selected person in the The above list.

I took the lead with Ajax before discovering that it was necessary to use a Wordpress statement:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_do_ajax', 'notre_fonction_ajax');
```

I still do not manage to pass my variable (value PersonName) in order to make my reqête to the next field.

So I have a JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#nomPersonne').mouseleave(function(){
      doAjaxRequest();
 });
});
function doAjaxRequest(){

 jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data:{
           'action':'do_ajax',
           'fn':'get_id_value'
           },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success:function(data){
                jQuery("#nomOrgani").html(data);
                         },
      error: function(errorThrown){
           alert('error');
           console.log(errorThrown);
      }

 });

}
```

My function in function.php:

function notre_fonction_ajax(){

// ce switch lancera les fonctions selon la valeur qu'aura notre variable 'fn'

```
 switch($_REQUEST['fn']){
      case 'get_id_value':
           $output = ajax_get_id_value($_REQUEST['count']);
      break;
      default:
          $output = 'No function specified, check your jQuery.ajax() call';
      break;

 }
```

// Maintenant nous allons transformer notre résultat en JSON et l'afficher

```
 $output=json_encode($output);
 if(is_array($output)){
    print_r($output);
 }
 else{
    echo $output;
 }
 die;

}

function ajax_get_id_value(){
function ajax_get_id_value(){

include_once 'connexion.php';

$term = $_GET['term']; 

$requete = $link->prepare("SELECT `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
JOIN `wp_term_relationships` ON `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` =  'wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` 
JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` ON `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` =  `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id`
JOIN `wp_terms` ON `wp_terms`.`term_id` = `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id`
WHERE `wp_terms`.`name` = 'Malaysia Airlines' AND  `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`='organization' AND `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` LIKE :term ");

$requete->execute(array('term' => '%' . $term . '%'));

$array = array(); // on créé le tableau

while ($donnee = $requete->fetch()) { // on effectue une boucle pour obtenir les données
array_push($array, $donnee['meta_value']); // et on ajoute celles-ci à notre tableau
}

echo json_encode($array); // il n'y a plus qu'à convertir en JSON
}
}
```

In this file, I set the" Malaysia Airlines "but it's actually the variable that I should recover.

When I look in Firebug, I see the answer: ["Malaysia Airlines"] on the console but I can not get that value to use in my next query

Anyway, I just finished my course I am in training and I have a little trouble to make them work together all languages, CMS, etc ...

For now my brains is like jelly... If someone has some lights, I will be eternally grateful!

Kaelig.

Comment: Sola, perduta, abbandonata...

Comment: I'll get back to it this weekend, if you have suggestions ...

Comment: I think I made a mistake somewhere in the logic, I think that I am going to restart everything from zero.

I have two lists (Personne & organisation), filled by autocomplete if data exist in the BDD, this part is working.
Then I would like to get back both fields selected to make a request to show the corresponding data in BDD if it exist.
I wanted to improve by filling the second field according to what is seized in the first one.
How would proceed you to the simplest and most effective?
Have a nice day !

Comment: I have in my JS file functions to retrieve the inputs of PersonName and nomOrgani and corresponding php functions work:

FOR PersonName: File JS

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#nomPersonne').change(function(){
      doAjaxRequest1();
 });
});
function doAjaxRequest1(){
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data:{
           'action':'do_ajax',
           'fn':'get_pers_value', 
           'value': document.getElementById("nomPersonne").value
           },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success:function(data){
                //alert('çà marche !');
                         },
      error: function(errorThrown){
           alert('error');
           console.log(errorThrown);
      }
 });
 }
```

FOR nomOrgani: File JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#nomOrgani').change(function(){
      doAjaxRequest2();
 });
});

 function doAjaxRequest2(){

  jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data:{
           'action':'do_ajax',
           'fn':'get_org_value', 
           'value': document.getElementById("nomOrgani").value
           },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success:function(data){
          //alert('çà marche !');      
          show('signalIntox');
                         },
      error: function(errorThrown){
           alert('error');
           console.log(errorThrown);
      }

 });

}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_do_ajax', 'notre_fonction_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_do_ajax', 'notre_fonction_ajax');
function notre_fonction_ajax(){
    // ce switch lancera les fonctions selon la valeur qu'aura notre variable 'fn'
     switch($_REQUEST['fn']){
      case 'get_pers_value':
           $output = ajax_get_pers_value('value');
      break;
      case 'get_org_value':
           $output = ajax_get_org_value('value');
      break;
      default:
          $output = 'No function specified, check your jQuery.ajax() call';
      break;
 }
 // Maintenant nous allons transformer notre résultat en JSON et l'afficher
 $output=json_encode($output);
 if(is_array($output)){
    print_r($output);
 }
 else{
    echo $output;
 }
 die;
}
function ajax_get_pers_value($nomPersonne){
$nom = $_REQUEST['value'];
return $nom;
}  
function ajax_get_org_value($nomOrgani){
$org = $_REQUEST['value'];
return $org;
}
```

So everything does work as I get the value of the two inputs in firebug "GET admin-ajax.php? Action ..." In the response tab that displays the value, such as "NAME PERSON "and as for the organization.

Now, with the values ​​I want to make a request for:
For nomPersone value, deduce all organizations to find in BDD
Value for nomOrgani and PersonName: make the application with both names to display the contents of the post with this names.
I think, that  the success party function (data) send to a php file to make my requests ... to follow!

Answer (score 0):

```
function doAjaxRequest1(){
     jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          data:{
               'action':'do_ajax',
               'fn':'get_pers_value', 
               'value': document.getElementById("nomPersonne").value
               },
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success:function(data){
                    //alert('çà marche !');
                    createCookie('nom',document.getElementById("nomPersonne").value,0);
                    console.log(readCookie('nom'));
                    alert(readCookie('nom')); 
                    },
          error: function(errorThrown){
               alert('error');
               console.log(errorThrown);
          }
     });
 }
```

Now, I created functions in Javascript to set and get cookies.
I've tried in my succes function and it works !

But now I have to use these cookies in my SQL requests to display my informations.
Not sure how to mix javascript and SQL, suggestions welcome...
Have a nice day.
Kaelig.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite solved ...but almost; actually I have a time lag in my cookies, the second arrives late, so to speak ... I have the 'nom' for the first request and  'org' of the second.On the other hand, if I fill the fields twice in the same ways the good info is displayed well, so the SQL query and display is working once both good cookies are recorded.In addition, it only works on Firefo. In Chrome and IE on the second autocomplete list is not displayed and in chrome dev tool I foundthe cookie 'org' but not the cookie 'nom' .. .
I'm not very far away, I persevere !
Have a nice day.
Kaelig.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I have nested one Ajax call in another Ajax call.
When I create the second cookie I call (Ajax) to create the div (query and display).
It's a bit convoluted but basically it works, does not display all the views I want, but I think this is a problem in the query itself.
In any case the "Ajax engine" works!
Thank you.
Have a nice day.
Kaelig.